# Parsing a number or number plus fraction from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have some strings that contain numbers (sometimes) like

```
1 teaspoon garlic
1/2 cup of butter
1 1/2 ounce yogurt
```

I'm trying to parse out the numerical part(including the fractions).  So

```
1 teaspoon garlic = "1"
1/2 cup of butter = "1/2"
1 1/2 ounce yogurt = "1 1/2"
```

I have some regex that I thought was correct that looks like

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^\(\d+(\d*|\s\d+\/\d+)\)$");
var match = re.Match(input);
```

Doesn't seem to be working though. How I can parse out the matching regex from a string?

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a duplicate being as I'm not trying to convert these to a double by doing math on the results here and just really only care about how to parse out the values using regex. Not by splitting strings on spaces and /

Comment: Hey, Matthew. I was working on a regex to parse out the fractional parts when Nkosi closed it. Now I've only tested this in Python, but the grouping and everything works for me. `r'((?P<whole>[0-9]+)\s(?P<numerator>[0-9]+)\/(?P<denominator>[0-9]+))'`. Mind you, I don't know what C# regex is like.

Comment: [`\d(?:[\d \/]*\d)?`](https://regex101.com/r/JeIK0G/1)

Comment: Oh nice! I need to spend more time on my regex.

Comment: @slai is correct. This seems to work. I guess all these years of avoiding regex is coming back to haunt me. Thanks guys.